# How to make shortcuts for letters

Tags: lyx

I have installed LYX on Kubuntu and Hebrew fonts for LYX. So In Hebrew we have vowels, for example if under a letter we have a dot or two dots it has a different sound. So when I installed the Hebrew fonts, it installed these vowels as well. When I do caps lock or shift+key it would put the vowels. But in every program (other than LyX, such as word, Chrome...), when I write in Hebrew and I do caps lock or shift+letter, when the Hebrew is on, it would write capital Latin letters (Depending on the key I am pressing). And that is how I got used to it. And I want to do the same for LyX. Instead of having vowels when I do caps lock (or shift+key) instead of having vowels I want to have the capital letter in Latin (Depending on the key that I am pressing) to be written. Does anyone have any idea I can change that? I tried Tools--> Preferences--> Editing-> Shortcuts but I don't have anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the file `lib/kbd/hebrew.kmap` to the `kbd` directory in your user directory (by default ~/.lyx). Then edit it accordingly.

There is a section with the first few lines as

```
# The following lines prevent entering capitals letters in a Hebrew text
\kmap Q /
\kmap W '
\kmap E ק
\kmap R ר
\kmap T א
\kmap Y ט
\kmap U ו
\kmap I ן
\kmap O ם
\kmap P פ
```

I think you want to delete that section.

Do this without LyX running, then start LyX. I'm not sure if you need to do a Tools > Reconfigure (and restart LyX one more time).